# IE11 Plugin downloads to my C drive but I can't find the files (Win 10)

Tags: windows-10

I have a plugin for IE11 that downloads files to my C drive.  IE11 isolates the C drive, at least, for security purposes.  Sandbox, Protected Mode.  ActiveX.

Where can I find my files that appear to be successfully downloaded but are visible only through the file dialogs of IE11?

Comment: What plugin? Your question is pretty useless without this information.

Comment: The specific plugin is irrelevant to the tip.  All ie11 activex plugins (noticable as those which allow you to export/save a file to disk) will be quarantined in this way.  It will seem like your file save is successful, but when you try to find it from Explorer, it will not be where you thought you saved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 10, you can find the virtualized drive here:

> C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\C